# New Graphic Card Not Working

Tags: graphics-card, pci

I bought a new graphic card for my PC, before I had a 8400GS and now I've bought a VTX ATI 5450 card, however, after installing it, my computer stopped booting and made a clicking sound through the internal speaker.

I tried this card on a different PC and it is working fine.

If I remove the card the PC works again.

I've double checked cables. I've taken the PC to bare bones with the graphic card and the same problem still occurs. Also swapped out the PSU with a GS700 and the problem was still there (The [GS700 is a certified power supply unit](http://support.amd.com/us/certified/power-supplies/Pages/listing.aspx) by AMD).

My Specs are the following:

- Abit SG-95 motherboard.
- Pentium D 3.2.
- 2.5GB RAM.
- 230V 400W PSU.
- ATI 5450 Graphic card that I'm trying to install.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that the power of the PSU is insufficient to power the new video card? Could you verify with the PSU rating of the "different PC"

Comment: He needs 400 watts, 1 gig of ram and an x16 lane, all of which he appears to have.

Comment: @dave the internet. http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5450-overview/pages/hd-5450-overview.aspx#3

Comment: @Snesticle. Power = PSU :)

Comment: I've tried making it work with bare bones, so only cpu, ram and graphic card connected but results are the same. It fails to output anything and makes a weird clicking sound through the internal speakers.

Comment: 400 watt PSU *minimum* is required. There is a possibility its power related and also the PCIe slot could be defective. Check your BIOS to ensure the slot is enabled as primary video.

Comment: @david I'd always assumed PSU was a recursive acronym like GNU. Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: Its just a standard PSU, it could be power issues I suppose, I hooked it up to my main PC with a GS700 and it started working, but I am sure that PCIe slot is fine because it works with the older card

Comment: Okay I added a different PSU, the GS700 into the PC and still didn't work, same result, so that rules out not having enough power.

Comment: @user1860175 - Which means what Dave noticed is likely the reason its not working. The computer that isn't working will be unable to support the graphic card you purchased. Your power supply not supplying enough power could be a problem. What other hardware do you have connected to the power supply?

Comment: The old card used up to 71 Watt. (Source: http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_8400_Gs_faq.html ) The new card is fed of the PCIe bus, which supplies a maximum of 75 Watt. So I really doubt it is a power problem.

Comment: Like I said I've tried it with a seperate 700W PSU, and it still gives the same problem. I'll contact ATI and Abit and see what they say, if I can that is.

Answer (score 1):

The [card you have bought is PCI-E 2.1](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5450-overview/pages/hd-5450-overview.aspx#2)

Your [motherboard](http://static.tigerdirect.com/pdf/ABIT_SG-95_Manual.pdf) has PCI-E 1 slots.

Now, some cards can work on PCI-E 1, some at reduced performance and others fine, but not all. I suspect yours cannot due to the AMD site not declaring it is compatible.

Please note, there are posts on the forums that some have fried their motherboard by attempting what you are, so do proceed very carefully. To be honest, my suggestion in the comments of trying a more powerful PSU may have been ill-advised as it could have caused damage.

Comment: According to the standard, all PCI-e v2.x cards *should* work in a PCI-e v1 slot. And all PCI-e slots *should* be able to supply up to 75 Watt power via the PCI-e slot (The card has no extra power connectors and feeds of PCI-e supplied power). So it should just work. -- @user1860175 Does the card work in another system?

Comment: @Hennes , I agree, but we both know *should* means nothing :)! Yes, his card words on another machine. This is a post with similar question which may be interesting reading http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/340557-15-pcie-card-pcie

Comment: Aye. Hence my use of italic. (Which you picked up on, but which is hereby made explicit).

Comment: Yeah I'll have a read through that, and perhaps try contacting ATI support as well as Abit, I'll get back if they give a reply.